# Routing with two different gateways

Tags: networking, gateway

I have the following problem. I cant ping 8.8.4.4

```
ping -I ens192 8.8.4.4

PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) from 192.168.4.44 ens192: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1023ms


ping -I ens192:1 8.8.4.4
ping: invalid source address ens192:1
```

My network consist of 1 Network interface and on second virtual on top of it. And two gateways for it. Both gateways need to be configuerd.

I checked befor and the google server is reachable with the normal gateway line in Debian. From both Gateways. 
So how do i get it to work ?

My interface config file

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens192
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address 192.168.4.44
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 dev ens192 src 192.168.4.44 table rt1
        post-up ip route add default via 192.168.4.1 dev ens192 table rt1
        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.4.44/32 table rt1
        post-up ip rule add to 192.168.4.44/32 table rt1

auto ens192:1
allow-hotplug ens192:1
iface ens192:1 inet static
        address 192.168.4.201
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 dev ens192:1 src 192.168.4.201 table rt2
        post-up ip route add default via 192.168.4.3 dev ens192 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.4.201/32 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add to 192.168.4.201/32 table rt2
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- Pass the IP address of the interface on `-I`. I.e. `-I 192.168.4.201`
- The default route on the second interface says `dev ens192` instead of `dev ens192:1`
- I guess that you either can't ping 192.168.4.1 and 192.168.4.3 or there is some additional configuration that's not shown here.